# By the book, was Dumbledore able to communicate with Harry after his death?

Tags: harry-potter

We all know Harry gave the elder wand to Dumbledore's corpse. But later communicated with his portrait about where he was keeping the wand and why.

> *"I'm putting the Elder Wand back where it came from. It can stay there. If I die a natural death like Ignotus, its power will be broken, won't it? The previous master will never have been defeated. That'll be the end of it."*
>
> *—Harry's decision to give up the Elder Wand*

So, why didn't Dumbledore explain everything to him in the first place if he could communicate ? If he had done so, Harry need not peek into Snape's memory and it would have been far more easier psychologically for him isn't it?

Comment: Strictly speaking Harry gave the Elder wand to Dumbledore's corpse, not his portrait

Comment: could you pls quote some lines...i dont remember it correctly..@JasonBaker

Comment: I don't have the book in front of me, but [DavRob60 covers it here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4835/31051). Even so, I don't fully understand your question; what should Dumbledore have told Harry?

Comment: possible dupe, but i'm not sure because your question is unclear: [Why didn't Dumbledore tell Harry that Snape was going to kill him?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/80077/5184)

Comment: @JasonBaker - I'm not sure the edit matches original intent? Hard to get the latter though

Comment: @DVK I don't take your meaning; the OP added the quote, I just added formatting

Comment: This question seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you are asking why Dumbledore didn't communicate to Harry specifically about Death Stick:

  - His plan was for the Elder Wand to stay with his tomb and thus be irrelevant to Harry/Voldemort later struggle as an object
  - Telling Harry about Elder Wand would get Harry to know about Hallows "prematurely", according to Dumbledore's judgement. He later admitted that he was wrong in that timing assessment in *King's Cross" chapter.
- If you are asking why Dumbledore didn't communicate to Harry the whole thing he got out of Snape's memory"

  same reason: he didn't consider Harry to be ready to hear the truth at the time he was still alive. And harry had no way to speak to Dumbledore's portrait till after Snape's death.